# Estimation of DS graph growth

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, graph-theory

We know that $DS$ graphs are such connected graphs that determinable by their adjacency spectrum.

Suppose $DS(n)$ and $G(n)$ show the number of $DS$ graphs and all graphs with $n$ vertices,respectively.

$1)$ Do we have any good approximation for $DS(n)$(even if $n$ be sufficiently large)?

$2)$ what is the behavior of $‎\alpha$, if we have:

‎ 
$lim (DS(n)‎‎/ (G(n)-DS(n))^\alpha=c‎\neq‎0)$

$n ‎\rightarrow‎‎ ‎\infty‎$

Is there any new survey about DS graphs, after 2010?

Comment: Haemers conjectures that the proportion of graphs characterized by their spectrum goes to 1 as $n$ increases. And I am wondering how often you expect the topic to be surveyed.

Comment: When the time of growing of tulips comes, in every land, tulips will grow."BOLYAI"

I designed some problems that are interesting for me and I have some plan for solving them. I searched a lot about them, but I didn't found exact answer.

Many of my personal problem, as I see here, worked before.
What do you think Dear Godsil? Is it good or bad?

Please give me reference about this conjecture.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the computation of these values up to 11 vertices by van Dam and Haemers is still the best result.  No asymptotics are known.

Comment: For us ignoramus, what ARE DS graphs?

Comment: Shahrooz's first line is a definition, even though it doesn't look like one. A graph is DS if it is the only graph whose adjacency matrix has that characteristic polynomial. This is not standard terminology.

Comment: Dear McKay, I found a paper with name "Cospectral graphs on 12 vertices"(A. E. Brouwer, E. Spence).